# Google colab: Getting ModuleNotFoundError when importing

Tags: exception, google-colaboratory, python-import, modulenotfounderror

In my project called rp, I have a script te.py in location rp/Sc/el/te.py In my script te.py I have a import statement

```
from Sc.el.bo import Boo
```

In google colab I have the following code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
!cp -r /content/drive/MyDrive/rp /content
!python3 /content/rp/Sc/el/te.py
```

But it is giving me

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Sc'
```

If have done

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/rp')
```

But it is still failing. How do I resolve this.